# How do I implement simple user/password using WebClient and WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I am fairly familiar with Windows Authorization and have a method for adding roles I use in a local db.  Since this tool is located in an untrusted domain I looked at Basic Authentication but the solutions I see are way overboard in their huge explainations of Owin and OAuth, way beyond what I need.

The solution uses Powershell `PSCmdlet` to send data to a database for processing logs from an automated client process.  This is simple and awesome for low maintenance and ease of expansion but we need to have at least a modicum of control for the access.

The `WebClient` code is a simple call to an `async` method.  Ignoring try/catch for these examples:

```
private async Task<string> Run(string postBody)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = Common.DefaultMediaType;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

        var response = await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, postBody);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want to do something like this as a controller:

```
public partial class TestReportController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Team Member")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> TestConnectionPost()
    {
        dynamic message = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Sort the data and store it for later review
        // ...

        return "Data log confirmed: " + DateTime.Now();
    }
}
```

How do I access this `Credential`?  I would like to do something in the `Global.asax.cs` file to the `WebApiApplication` class that would cause this behavior.  My method for handling domain users is this for a website would be like:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) return;

    using (var db = new SecurityRoleEntities())
    {
        var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var userEntry = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdSid.ToLower().Equals(user.Identity.Name.ToLower()));
        var roles = FindRolesByUser(userEntry);

        if(roles == null) return;
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity();
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
            ClaimsPrincipal.Current.AddIdentity(id);
        }
    }
}
```

From a domain perspective in a browser, this works well.  The reporting tool is not in a domain level website though, it is run through IIS on a standalone server dedicated to servicing this tool.  **How can I implement Credentials from a WebClient to use simple authorization?**  Can it be done like this?

Comment: I ran into a kind fo similar situation. This blogged helped me out well. http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter

Comment: Definitely a better description and explanation than the www.asp.net site.  Still seems like there should be a packaged solution somewhere for this that is less involved.

Comment: Yeah i agree. Will look at this post for some time.